# Create airflow environment variables

Tags: python, variables, airflow

I am very much new to the airflow and need to create environment variables start_date and end_date in airflow UI under admin tab in variables section using the code

```
Variable.set("start_date")
Variable.set("end_date")
```

and then retrieving the values of start_date and end_Date passed from airflow UI using

```
Variable.get("start_date")
Variable.get("end_date")
```

[image]
However not getting success because variables are not creating in airflow UI under admin tab in variables section using the code

Can anyone please help me ,how to create the variables using code and then retrieve the values

Answer (score 1):

Airflow variables stores on the airflow database and it use the **key, value** structure to store and query variables. So if you want to set any variables on airflow do this on the UI:
[image]

Also, it's recommended to use JSON value if you use **start_date** and **end_date** for example on a specific dag because of it reduce querying from 2 times to 1 time like this:
[image]

Then you can use the variable like this:

```
variable = Variable.get("smaple")
start_date = variable['start_date']
end_date = variable['end_date']
```